# Mapbox studio : how to display building at any zoom level

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-studio

I'm using mapbox studio to customize a map and I haven't found the way to display building-outline layer at any zoom level.

If I'm under of 16 zoom level, this layer disappears... even if I force opacity to 1.

Any idea ?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3):

The minimum zoom level for the `buildings` layer in the current tileset (Mapbox Streets v8) is 13.

This means that if you zoom out further (from 12 to 0) the `buildings` layer will not be rendered on the map.

See documentation:

- https://docs.mapbox.com/vector-tiles/reference/mapbox-streets-v8/#layer-reference

The reason for this restriction is that if you requested your browser to fetch and render every building polygon in a wider area (like an entire city or country), this would be more than a reasonable amount of data to render.

If you have your own buildings polygon data and you create a tileset from that, you could choose to include your data across more zoom levels. However, you might waste a lot of computing resources drawing shapes that are too tiny to understand at those further zoom levels.